# Cognos 10 Row cumulative expression

Tags: websphere, cumulative-sum, cognos-10

Im trying to make a cumulative formula to add the percentages up in the row with the percentages before it. it can be a random amount of columns ranging from 1 to 15 for example.

This shows me the percentages in a crosstab. i just need to make another crosstab that cumulatively adds the percentages

'percentage(Count( [Pickticket Control Number]))'

I've tried running totals and not manages to make headway. any help would be great.

for context there are 3 crosstabs. One is count of pickktickets, two is count of picktickets as % and third needs to be count of picktickets cumulative as a percentage.

Comment: What results are you getting with the running total function and how does it differ from what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Show an example please